# Annoying simple issue, Sending data to other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Kal Calendar, and I need to give users the ability to insert a row, that's a whole other story.

Kal Calendar is applied by Assigning its class to a view controller, and it generates the View.

So, I decided to make an insert bar, where a user can click, and get sent to another view controller, where he can insert a value.

But for that, I need to add a bar, so I added Kal inside a container of the main view controller, so I could add the bar via storyboard.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/zahm.png/

So, now I need to get the selected date, over to the "Insert" view controller, when the user clicks on the + button.

The issue is that I cannot seem to pass the value, I tried a few differnet methods, and I'm getting null.

Inside the Kal ViewController, the Selected date is printed here, and its fired on ViewDidLoad, so it's guaranteed to be set.

```
- (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate*)date{
NSLog(@"Date Selected: %@",date);

    self.dateSelected = date; // i set it for the property here

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So, I tried to do it by creating an instance of the insert view, in Kal calendar, and setting the date there, but I then found out that another instance would be used if I segued via storyboard.

Any suggestions on what to do? Maybe set it up in a whole different way .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller that you get with the container view is a child view controller, so you can reference it from the parent (the controller whose view has the container view in it) with self.childViewControllers[0]. In your case, it looks like ViewControllerCalendar is the parent and CalendarMonthViewController is the child, in which you have the dateSelected property. If the modal segue to ViewControllerInsert is from the + button, then you should be able to pass the date to that controller in prepareForSegue:sender: like this (this code would be in your container controller, ViewControllerCalendar):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Insert"]) {
        ViewControllerInsert *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
        dest.passedInDate = [(CalendarMonthViewController *)self.childViewControllers[0] dateSelected];
    }
}
```

In my example here, I made up a name for the segue, "Insert", and a name for an NSDate property, passedInDate, that you would need in ViewControllerInsert.

Comment: No, thanks the next controller that has to know the value of date, picked in the Child of the far left container

Comment: Sorry for the late response, here is the markup: ViewControllerCalendarContainer, ViewControllerCalendar, ViewControllerInsert, the names should explain the setup

Comment: The redirect is in the Container, the data is in the Calendar and it has to be passed to Insert its a stupid setup, but its the best i could do with my limited Cocoa / IOS / Obj C skills

Comment: @JohnDOe, I'm still confused. Is the embedded controller (the one in the container view) the CalendarMonthViewController?

Comment: Yes it is, that is the one :)

Comment: @JohnDOe, It's not clear why you added a container view, it doesn't seem necessary. Can't you just add a tool bar to the Kal Calendar view controller, or does that not work?

Comment: and no its overwritten if i do it via storyboard